# How to apply Multiple ng-pattern with or condition in input box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Condition first: /^([a-zA-Z]{5})(\d{4})([a-zA-Z]{1})$/;
Condition second : (/^([a-zA-Z]){4}([0-9]){5}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/g)

html

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="userDetail.id" name="uid" required="" ng-pattern="regx"  />


Angular 
scope.regx= Condition first or condition Second

scope.regx=/^([a-zA-Z]{5})(\d{4})([a-zA-Z]{1})$/ || /^([a-zA-Z]){4}([0-9]){5}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/g;  not working
```

Comment: you want to check for both regx or just one depending upon the condition?

Comment: yes i want regx for check or  condition  between out of two conditions

Comment: A special construct (?ifthen|else) allows you to create conditional regular expressions. [checkthislink](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

Comment: you mean scope.regx= ? ^([a-zA-Z]{5})(\d{4})([a-zA-Z]{1})$/ : /^([a-zA-Z]){4}([0-9]){5}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/g;

Comment: i just need a add a two conditions in one or pan another for tan with single input

Comment: `^(?:(?=^([a-zA-Z]{5})(\d{4})([a-zA-Z]{1})$)|(?!^([a-zA-Z]){4}([0-9]){5}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work in your case.

```
/(?:(?=(^[a-zA-Z]{5}\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}$))|(?=(^[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{5}[a-zA-Z]{1}?$)))/g
```

Explaination: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much  Keyur shah  but I am using  "/^(([a-zA-Z]{5})|([a-zA-Z]){4})((\d{4})|([0-9]){5})([a-zA-Z]{1})$/g;" i'ts working fine

Comment: @HarishVerma this BLRBB55556G, AABCB55765G test case will return false positive by using your regex i.e  `/^(([a-zA-Z]{5})|([a-zA-Z]){4})((\d{4})|([0-9]){5})([a-zA-Z]{1})$/g;`. My answer works better.