# Condition based ng-pattern

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern

I want the ng-pattern value to change based on a condition like :

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="emialid" ng-pattern="<codition> ? <regex1> : <regex2>" name="email" required></input>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587499/how-to-apply-multiple-ng-pattern-with-or-condition-in-input-box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply Multiple ng-pattern with or condition in input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587499/how-to-apply-multiple-ng-pattern-with-or-condition-in-input-box)

Comment: @slacker - This is not a duplicate question as i want the ng-pattern to take  one value on the basis of a condition while the above questions you told, just give an OR in the regex irrespective of any condition.